# AEM 6.x replication(ReplicationActionType.DELETE) doesn't work

Tags: java, aem

So I'm trying to import some content from an Excel spreadsheet and save this to AEM.

After saving it to author, the data gets replicated to the publisher.

As part of the pre-import processes, I am deleting the destination folder and then recreate it.

The issue is that while the destination folder gets deleted in author, it doesn't get deleted in publisher.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

```
@Override
public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap) throws WorkflowException {
    try {
        Session session = workflowSession.getSession();
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = getResourceResolver(session);

        deleteNodes(session, resourceResolver);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("fish importer: Error in Fish Import Service", e);
    }
}

private void deleteNodes(Session session, ResourceResolver resolver) throws RepositoryException, ReplicationException, PersistenceException {
    Resource resource = resolver.getResource(rootPath); //rootPath = /content/data/fishes
    if (resource != null){
        Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
        String name  = node.getName();
        Node parent = node.getParent();

        node.remove();
        replicate(rootPath, session, ReplicationActionType.DELETE);
        resolver.commit();

        Node nodeCourses = parent.addNode(name, "nt:folder");
    }
}

protected void replicate(String path, Session jcrSession, ReplicationActionType activateType) throws ReplicationException {
    if (activateType.equals(ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE)) {
        replicator.replicate(jcrSession, activateType, path);
    } else {
        ReplicationStatus status = replicator.getReplicationStatus(jcrSession, path);
        if (status != null && status.isActivated()) {
            replicator.replicate(jcrSession, activateType, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any messages in the error log file when the workflow is running?

Comment: A few things come to mind. For one I think to "delete" something from publish instances you can use `DEACTIVATE` instead of `DELETE`. I also noticed that you deleted the node and then you pass the replicator the path of the node you just deleted. I am not 100% sure but that might be an issue.

Comment: As @Jens said, use `DEACTIVATE`. If you look at the default page deletion workflow `/etc/workflow/models/request_for_deletion.html`, it first deactivates the page and then deletes it from the author.